# downloading file from a SFTP server using Azure Runbook Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, sftp, azure-automation, azure-runbook

How can I install Posh-SSH in a Runbook Powershell?

I need to download files from a SFTP server to Azure Disk using a Runbook Powershll. However there is no Powershell mothod for this and I need to install Posh-ssh module. When I execute `Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -Force` inside my Runbook it generates following error:

Exception calling "ShouldContinue" with "2" argument(s): "A command that prompts the user failed because the host
program or the command type does not support user interaction. The host was attempting to request confirmation with the
following message: PowerShellGet requires NuGet provider version '2.8.5.201' or newer to interact with NuGet-based
repositories. The NuGet provider must be available in 'C:\Program Files\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies' or
'C:\Users\Client\AppData\Roaming\PackageManagement\ProviderAssemblies'. You can also install the NuGet provider by
running 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force'. Do you want PowerShellGet to install
and import the NuGet provider now?"

Comment: The error message states that it's waiting for a confirm prompt (but since interactive prompts are not possible within the host Azure Automation uses you can't click yes or no). You can use -Conform:$False to auto approve this OR (even better): install the module within Azure Automation (this is the supported scenario) on the Modules part.

Comment: Thanks. How can I install the module within Azure Automation?

Comment: I tried -Conform:$False, but it says: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Conform'.

I downloaded Posh-SSH module as zip file from Github and tried to import it to Azure automation, but it failed. it says: "Error importing the module Posh-SSH-master. Import failed with the following error: 
Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: Cannot import the module of name Posh-SSH-master, as the module structure was invalid."

Comment: In Azure Automation there is a blade called "modules" where you can upload your own (zipped) modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import this module as per steps below:

**1.Go** to your Automation account in azure portal.

**2.Under** Shared Resources, select Modules.

**3.Select** Add a module.

**4.Select** the **.zip file** that contains your module.

**5.Select** OK to start to import process.

The official document is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#import-modules). I also attach a screenshot of the progress here:

[image]